# Adding with-meta data to clojure structures

Tags: clojure

I want to add meta-data to different items in a map, but I get an error in Clojure if I rry this with:

```
{:a 
    (with-meta 
        1
        {:some-meta-tag "some-meta-data-value"}
    )
}
```

: Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could be wrong, but think you can't attach metadata to a number:

```
user=> (with-meta 1 {:meta-tag "foo"})
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IObj
```

From the [docs](http://clojure.org/metadata)

"Symbols and collections support metadata, a map of data about the symbol or collection."

This seemed to work:

```
user=> {:a (with-meta 'foo {:meta-tag "foo"})}
{:a foo}
```

And

```
user=> (meta (:a {:a (with-meta 'foo {:meta-tag "foo"})}))
{:meta-tag "foo"}
```

Comment: thanks, that worked with a set, just what I was looking for actually!

Comment: Correct. Built-in Java types (String, Number, ...) cannot have metadata.